# Django rest nested APIView routes

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm relatively new to Django & Django rest - previously built only very simple apps.
Currently facing a problem with using a nested routes.
Here are my related configs:

**main urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^'+root_url+'/swagger', swagger_schema_view),
    url(r'^' + root_url + '/', include('payments.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**app's urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'payments', views.PaymentsView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'payments/charge', views.PaymentsChargeView.as_view(), name='charge'),
]
```

**app's views:**

```
import logging

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from mysite.csrf_exempt import CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

import stripe
try:
    from django.conf import settings
except ImportError:
    pass



logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class PaymentsView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('here GET PaymentsView')
        return Response('good')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('here POST PaymentsView')
        return Response('good')


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class PaymentsChargeView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('here GET PaymentsChargeView')
        return Response('good')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('here POST PaymentsChargeView')
        return Response('good post')
```

**Problem:**

requests both to `/payments` and `/payments/charge` GET/POST always processed by `PaymentsView` (ex: `POST` to `/payments` and to `/payments/charge` gives me 'here POST PaymentsView' in console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to  put `$ (end-of-string match character)` in your url. So the defined url will match and process the correct view function.

```
url(r'payments$', views.PaymentsView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'payments/charge$', views.PaymentsChargeView.as_view(), name='charge'),
```

Answer (score 0):

change your url order

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'payments/charge', views.PaymentsChargeView.as_view(), name='charge'),
    url(r'payments', views.PaymentsView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^payments', views.PaymentsView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^payments/charge', views.PaymentsChargeView.as_view(), name='charge'),
]
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)